# How to query ElasticSearch to find objects with at least one term not in array

Tags: elasticsearch

In this problem, say we have a mapping like

```
{
  tags: { type: 'string' }, // array of strings input
  name: { type: 'string' }
}
```

Where tags is given an array. Say we then index the following documents:

```
[{
  tags: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  tags: ['b', 'c', 'd'],
  name: 'Beta'
}, {
  tags: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
  name: 'Gamma'
}, {
  tags: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
  name: 'Delta'
}, {
  tags: [],
  name: 'Eta'
}]
```

Is there a way to structure a query such that it can find all documents that have at least one tag **not** in a given array? For example, **given ['b', 'c', 'd']**, it should return the objects named **`Alpha`** (which has 'a' not in the given array), **`Gamma`** (which has 'e' not in the given array) and **`Delta`** (which also has 'e' not in the given array).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the 'input array' concept as a boolean query - this will work

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "tags": "b"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "tags": "c"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "tags": "d"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must" : { "wildcard" : {"tags": "*"}},
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirmal. Thanks for the suggestion. It's close, but it fails if a document has all of the blacklisted terms, plus another that isn't. I updated the example above now to illustrate this. The document named Delta would not be returned by this because it does not satisfy any of the should clauses, even though it has the "e" tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible, because Elasticsearch stores data in [inverted indexes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html), a data structure that can answer a question "which documents have a certain token", rather than "which documents do not have other tokens".

There are a couple of things you can try.

### Specify matching `tags` explicitly

This can be done if the set of all possible `tags` is known beforehand, and the cardinality of the field (== the number of unique tags) is not too high (say, less than 1000).

If the set of possible values is not known, it can be fetched via a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation. In this case you will have to do 2 queries instead of 1.

In the example from your question it would mean to ask for all documents that have tags in `["a", "e"]`.

### Use `script` query

[`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-script-query.html) query is essentially a [full-scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) query, and allows the user to define match/not match criteria as one pleases. The main disadvantage is the performance, since Elasticsearch will not be able to use any of its inverted indexes, it will essentially have to scan all the documents.

This option might prove useful in some circumstances, like to perform an analysis or prove some hypothesis.

### Reshape the data

Since a generic approach is not feasible, it may turn out that your business-case is actually not generic. Take a look at the queries you need to do, and optimize for your use-cases.

For instance, if searching for "any tags *but* **b, c, d**" is repetitive use-case, define a flag-like field `"contains_not_b_c_d"` and pre-compute it.

I really wish I could come up with something more positive in this answer, but this use-case is not where Elasticsearch thrives.

---

Hope that helps!